# Better way to check multiple columns with the same condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I got the output but trying to find a more efficient way to do this:

```
(df['budget'] == 0).sum(), (df['revenue'] == 0).sum(),(df['budget_adj'] == 0).sum(), (df['revenue_adj'] == 0).sum()
```

Output is

```
(5674, 5993, 5676, 5993)
```

Comment: `df[['budget', 'revenue', 'budget_adj', 'revenue_adj']].eq(0).sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the columns in bulk and sum these up column-wise:

```
(df[['budget', 'revenue', 'budget_adj', 'revenue_adj']] == 0).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! that is what I was looking for